# Testing Python Packages

Tags: python

I have the source code to a python package that is typically installed using pup or easy-install. How do I locally install the code after I've made changes? I'd like to be able to run commands on the terminal as if I've installed it with pip and then reinstall/have it detect code changes to try it again.

Comment: `python setup.py install`

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Don't forget `python setup.py build` first

Comment: `install` calls `build` unless `skip_build` is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pip -e install <path-to-package>` to install a package in editable mode. Then, you can make changes to the source code, and not have to install it again.

This is best done, as always, in a `virtualenv`, so it is isolated from the rest of your system.

Comment: `python setup.py develop` will make the local copy available to the interpreter (via the system path) too.

Comment: ``python setup.py develop`` is (IIRC) distribute-only: it will not work with setuptools and distutils-based packages. Or something. It isn't always present.